# Tag < gets replaced by &lt; in Asp.Net GridView

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridView which gets data from the database. One of the fields contains a hyperlink.

The fields are Name and Details.

Sample text: `"School Name <a href='http://site/page.aspx'>School URL</a>".`

The Grid is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="grid" ID="grdSchool" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="grdSchoolIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="SortRecords" AllowPaging="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

The gridview gets its code form

```
dim dt as datatable= getGataFromDatabase()
grdSchool.DataSource = dt
```

When the page renders the `< tag` is replaced by `&lt;` so it appears as a text instead of a hyperlink. 
Is there a away I can escape the `<`tag so that it appears as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by using AutoGenerateColumns unfortunately. You'll have to list out all of the columns individually in order to get the amount of control you will need to do this. AutoGenerateColumns doesn't really give you any control over how the data will be displayed. It is meant more as a quick and easy way to display simple data.

The key thing you will need to do is make sure the GridView does not HTML encode the data. Luckily, an `<asp:BoundField>` has an `HtmlEncode` property. Just set it to false.

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="grid" ID="grdSchool" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="grdSchoolIndexChanging" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    OnSorting="SortRecords"
    AllowPaging="True"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="yourLinkColumn" HeaderText="yourLinkColumnHeader" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="yourNonLinkColumn" HeaderText="yourNonLinkColumnHeader" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```